# sedで文字列を取り出すにはどうやればいいでしょうか？

Tags: bash, sh, command-line, sed

`"_app_"`だけが必ず出現する`"aaa  bbb foo_app_bar  ccc ddd"`のような文字列から、`sed`を使って`"foo_app_bar"`を取り出したいです。

```
echo "aaa bbb foo_app_bar ccc ddd" | sed -n "s/.*\([^\s]*_app_[^\s]*\).*/\1/p"
```

を試してみましたが望みどおりに動作しませんでした。

どうやればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "aaa bbb foo_app_bar ccc ddd" | sed "s/.*[[:space:]]\([^[:space:]]\+_app_[^[:space:]]\+\).*/\1/"
```

GNU sedでは上記のようにすれば`"_foo_app_bar"`を取り出せました。

以下は[metropolis](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/16894/metropolis)さんからのコメントを元にしています。
BSD由来の`sed`の場合、`\s` や `[:space:]` などの正規表現が利用できない様ですね。例えば

```
echo"aaa bbb foo_app_bar ccc ddd" | sed 's/.*[ \t]\(.*_app_[^ \t]*\)[ \t].*/\1/'
```

とか。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。
ただ自分の環境では
``aaa bbb foo_app_bar ccc ddd`` と出力されてしまいます。

macOS 10.13.3 の標準でついている sed なのでこれが悪いのかな。。

Comment: @akidroid BSD由来のsedの場合、`\s` や `[:space:]` などの正規表現が利用できない様ですね。例えば `sed 's/.*[ \t]\(.*_app_[^ \t]*\)[ \t].*/\1/'` とか。

Comment: @metropolis そうだったんですね 。でもありがとうございます。
``sed 's/.*[ \t]\(.*_app_[^ \t]*\)[ \t].*/\1/'`` こちらで無事に動きました！！

Answer (score 0):

`grep` の `-o` オプションを利用するのはどうでしょうか？

```sh
$ echo "aaa bbb foo_app_bar ccc ddd test_app_" | grep -o '[^ ]*_app_[^ ]*'
foo_app_bar
test_app_
```